# A proper way to declare an JavaScript Options-Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

i wanted to access an API which responses with some JSON. Therefore I want to configure an 'options' object, which stores all the data which are needed to access the api (url, tokens, id, etc.).

The following version **works**:

```
var Options = function (token, id) {
  this.token = token;
  this.id = id;
  this.host = 'http://super-cool-api.com/';
  this.path = 'api/fetch/id/';
  this.url = '' + this.host + this.path + this.id + '?token=' + this.token
};
var options = new Options('abc', 3);

// options.url = "http://super-cool-api.com/api/fetch/id/3?token=abc"
```

Basically 'options.url' is all I want. But I've tried to declare a more comprehensive form for the 'options' object, like this:

```
var options = {
  token : 'abc',
  id : 3,
  host : 'http://super-cool-api.com/',
  path : 'api/fetch/id/',
  url : '' + this.host + this.path + this.id + '?token=' + this.token
};

// options.url = "undefinedundefinedundefined?token=undefined"
```

Okay, I understood that I have to access the values in options.url somehow else. But how? Is this even common practice?

What about my first solution? Is it recommended to do it this way?

Regards,
Christoph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `this` in your second example points to the object that contains the code, i.e. **NOT** `options`, that is why the variables are undefined. The first solution is fine, as would be:

```
function makeOptions(token, id) {
    var host = 'http://super-cool-api.com/',
        path : 'api/fetch/id/';
    return {
        token: token,
        id: id,
        host: host,
        path: path,
        url: '' + host + path + id + '?token=' + token
    };
}
```

Choose what suits you best.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways you show are OK ways of doing this, as for the most accepted / standard way of doing it, I wouldn't really know.

Here is an example of how to get the Second Option you showed to work correctly :

Set the `url` of options to be a function that builds the URL and returns it.

```
var options = {
    token : 'abc',
    id : 3,
    host : 'http://super-cool-api.com/',
    path : 'api/fetch/id/',
    url : function() {
        return '' + this.host + this.path + this.id + '?token=' + this.token;
    }
};
```

And then you can retrieve the value using the following : `var testUrl = options.url();`

Here is an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/aPdH2/1/) for both of your examples, plus my example (Option 3)